# GridDB C client, Failed to run sample1.c

Tags: griddb

When I install c_client on Github after I follow guid on Github.
Input the following command:

```
$ cp client/c/sample/sample1.c .
$ gcc -I./client/c/include -L./bin sample1.c -lgridstore
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:./bin
```

After I run file ***a.out***, I don't see result  but  I see the following notification: " *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* " ,
It isn't same result on Github. File ***sample1.c*** you can follow in link `https://github.com/griddb/c_client/blob/4.3-rc/client/c/sample/sample1.c` . Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked and executed sample1.c following GridDB Github.

It's OK with my environment.

I suggest:

- You need to check status of your database.
- You need to check container with your container name which is exist or not in your database
- If exist, please drop container. You need to update sample1.c with drop container
- If not, please debug and give more information about failed step.

Comment: thanks you so much. I checked container in my database, It already exists. I had dropcontainer and it run success.