# GridDB Java Client Sample1 does not complete

Tags: java, griddb

I am struggling to get [Java Sample1](https://docs.griddb.net/gettingstarted/using-rpmyum/#build-execution-method) to connect to the GS server.
It's probably not important, but I have set up to use [maven with GridDB](https://griddb.net/en/blog/using-maven-to-develop-griddb-applications/)

From what I can see, GridDB server starts up fine and this completes successfully:
`GridStore store = GridStoreFactory.getInstance().getGridStore(props);`

But `putCollection` never completes and never times out after any reasonable amount of time:
`Collection<String, Person> col = store.putCollection("col01", Person.class);`

Has anyone had any luck with the GridDB Java Samples?

I see that someone else had a similar issue with the [GridDB C client, Failed to run sample1.c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60426308/griddb-c-client-failed-to-run-sample1-c)
but none of those suggestions help.

Here is the entire gs_stat:

```
{
    "checkpoint": {
        "backupOperation": 0,
        "duplicateLog": 0,
        "endTime": 1705609464270,
        "mode": "NORMAL_CHECKPOINT",
        "normalCheckpointOperation": 1513,
        "pendingPartition": 0,
        "periodicCheckpoint": "ACTIVE",
        "requestedCheckpointOperation": 0,
        "startTime": 1705609464266
    },
    "cluster": {
        "activeCount": 1,
        "applyRuleLimitTime": "2024-01-18T20:00:06.365Z",
        "autoGoal": "ACTIVE",
        "clusterName": "myCluster",
        "clusterRevisionId": "128dd97f-d288-4c63-be2f-2526646f65c0",
        "clusterRevisionNo": 90777,
        "clusterStatus": "MASTER",
        "currentRule": "Initial",
        "designatedCount": 1,
        "loadBalancer": "ACTIVE",
        "master": {
            "address": "127.0.0.1",
            "port": 10040
        },
        "nodeList": [
            {
                "address": "127.0.0.1",
                "port": 10040
            }
        ],
        "nodeStatus": "ACTIVE",
        "notificationMode": "FIXED_LIST",
        "partitionStatus": "NORMAL",
        "startupTime": "2024-01-13T13:54:16.865Z",
        "syncCount": 2
    },
    "currentTime": "2024-01-18T20:24:36Z",
    "performance": {
        "backgroundMinRate": 0.1,
        "backupCount": 0,
        "checkpointFileFlushCount": 128,
        "checkpointFileFlushTime": 0,
        "checkpointWrite": 0,
        "checkpointWriteCompressTime": 0,
        "checkpointWriteSize": 0,
        "checkpointWriteTime": 0,
        "currentTime": 1705609476715,
        "dataFileAllocateSize": 0,
        "dataFileSize": 0,
        "dataFileUsageRate": 1,
        "expirationDetail": {
            "batchScanNum": 2000,
            "batchScanTotalNum": 0,
            "batchScanTotalTime": 0,
            "erasableExpiredTime": "",
            "estimatedBatchFree": 0,
            "estimatedErasableExpiredTime": "",
            "lastBatchFree": 0,
            "latestExpirationCheckTime": "Under measurement"
        },
        "logFileFlushCount": 256,
        "logFileFlushTime": 386,
        "numBackground": 0,
        "numConnection": 1,
        "numNoExpireTxn": 0,
        "numSession": 0,
        "numTxn": 0,
        "ownerCount": 128,
        "peakProcessMemory": 59564032,
        "poolBufferMemory": 0,
        "processMemory": 14118912,
        "sqlNumConnection": 1,
        "sqlStoreSwapRead": 0,
        "sqlStoreSwapReadSize": 0,
        "sqlStoreSwapReadTime": 0,
        "sqlStoreSwapWrite": 0,
        "sqlStoreSwapWriteSize": 0,
        "sqlStoreSwapWriteTime": 0,
        "storeCompressionMode": "NO_BLOCK_COMPRESSION",
        "storeDetail": {
            "batchFreeMapData": {
                "storeMemory": 0,
                "storeUse": 0,
                "swapRead": 0,
                "swapWrite": 0
            },
            "batchFreeRowData": {
                "storeMemory": 0,
                "storeUse": 0,
                "swapRead": 0,
                "swapWrite": 0
            },
            "mapData": {
                "storeMemory": 0,
                "storeUse": 0,
                "swapRead": 0,
                "swapWrite": 0
            },
            "metaData": {
                "storeMemory": 0,
                "storeUse": 0,
                "swapRead": 0,
                "swapWrite": 0
            },
            "rowData": {
                "storeMemory": 0,
                "storeUse": 0,
                "swapRead": 0,
                "swapWrite": 0
            }
        },
        "storeMemory": 0,
        "storeMemoryLimit": 1073741824,
        "storeTotalUse": 0,
        "swapRead": 0,
        "swapReadSize": 0,
        "swapReadTime": 0,
        "swapReadUncompressTime": 0,
        "swapWrite": 0,
        "swapWriteCompressTime": 0,
        "swapWriteSize": 0,
        "swapWriteTime": 0,
        "totalBackupLsn": 0,
        "totalLockConflictCount": 0,
        "totalOtherLsn": 0,
        "totalOwnerLsn": 0,
        "totalReadOperation": 0,
        "totalRowRead": 0,
        "totalRowWrite": 0,
        "totalWriteOperation": 0,
        "txnDetail": {
            "totalBackgroundOperation": 0
        }
    },
    "recovery": {
        "progressRate": 1
    },
    "version": "5.3.0-39942 CE"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

based on what I am seeing from the docs, if you are running the exact same command listed there, it will fail due to the network mode GridDB is running in.

previously, GridDB ran in multi-cast mode with a host and port of "239.0.0.1 31999", but it now runs in FIXED_LIST mode by default, with different credentials

host/post --> notification_member
239.0.0.1:31999 --> 127.0.0.1:10001

So, to successfully run the Java sample, you can edit the sample file itself to remove host & port and add in notification_member instead.

You can verify what mode you're in by using the gs_stat command from the gsadm user

Comment: gs_stat shows that gridstore Status is ok `"clusterStatus": "MASTER", "nodeStatus":  "ACTIVE", "partitionStatus": "NORMAL",`
At least I am getting a timeout now:  
`com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.GSTimeoutException: [145028:JC_BAD_CONNECTION]`

Comment: can you look for the following: 

"notificationMode": "FIXED_LIST",

Comment: Yep, it's there, @l-connell `"nodeStatus": "ACTIVE",
"notificationMode": "FIXED_LIST",
"partitionStatus": "NORMAL",
"startupTime": "2024-01-13T13:54:16.865Z",
"syncCount": 2`